# How do I print in black and white when the program does not support this?

Tags: pdf, printing

On a Windows system I use PDF24 and I can print from any application in black and white. I am looking for a similar option on macOS. Which PDF printer can I use for this purpose? The built-in does not offer this option.

[image: PDF24 PDF properties]

Comment: The standard print dialog actually has a black&white option. From which application do you want to print? Can you add a screenshot of the its print dialog?

Comment: If you are talking about creating a B&W PDF from a document, you might want to put that in the question title so it is more clear. Also, are you using a PDF specific printer driver on the Mac - if so which one? Normally on the Mac you would create a PDF using the "PDF" menu on the print window while a normal physical printer is selected and you should be able to use the controls provided by that driver to switch to B&W output.